# Lambda Expression isn't working

Tags: arrays, lambda

I have this class with an interface, and the method should only give the value at index 10 else give null back if it doesn't exist, my Method is always giving my the Last Value from the Array, what did I typed wrong in the lambda expression???

```
       public interface Intrifun {
 Integer apply(Integer p1, Integer p2, Integer p3);
}

public class IData {

 private Integer[] ivalues;
 public IData(Integer[] p)


 {
      ivalues = p;
  }
     public Integer dow(Intrifun itf) 
{
      Integer lastresult = null;
      for (int i = 0; i < ivalues.length; i++)
       {
       if (ivalues[i] != null)
           {
        lastresult = itf.apply(ivalues[i], lastresult, i);

           }
       }

  return lastresult;
 }
}
```

and this my test method :

```
  public static void main (String[]args)
        { Integer  [] tmp= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,};
          IData id= new IData(tmp);
          System.out.println(id.dow( (p1,p2,p3)-> {    if (p3==10){ return p1; 
              }  else {
                return null; }      
            } 
         ));    
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is fine, here is another variant via closure capturing:

int resultValue=0

id.dow( (p1,p2,p3)-> { if (p3==10) {resultValue=p1;}; return resultValue;})

Fell free to mark any of the answers as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does return null back which is not the last value of your collection and which is valid with respect to your code
as the last index of your integer array is not 10 and therefore you get null back.

Some remarks:

- I've tested it in jshell with Java 10
- It would be nice if you format
  your code better so that other users can help you more productively
- Why is your example so overly complicated given what you want to
  achieve, was your intention to learn lambdas?
- If your target was to
  get the 10th element then you have forgotten that later lambda calls
  return null back and that result is overwriting your 10th element in lastResult.

Comment: thanks for your respond ,yes i understand that  , yes its kind of uni assignment,  i should do it using lambda , though i can't edit the class Idata , i can only write in test method ,so my questions is how can i force the program to give back a certain index value and not the last one ? (im sorry about the code ,im kinda of new here and its  my first semester as an IT student );

Comment: Integer[] tmp={null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,2,null}; IData id = new IDATA(tmp); jshell> System.out.println(id.dow( (p1,p2,p3)-> {if (p3==10){return p1; }  else {return null; }      } ))
2
;So you set all integer array entries to null except at index 10 where you insert any number, then you get back that number; Sorry for formatting can't break as I want

Comment: sorry but i think your code gonna give at the end null ,because as he goes to the last index  he will give null (the else statment )            id.dow( (p1,p2,p3)-> {  if (p3==10) {p2=p1;}  return p2; } ) thats the soultion i figured it our and i posted the answear but i guess there is a proplem ;

Comment: @Fadi41, no the complete lambda is only called for index=10 as all other entries in tmp where null because of the condition:  if (ivalues[i] != null) :)